# Skip 'trace0' from hovertemplate of plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly

I have the `plotly` plot below and I want to skip this `"trace0"` value next to the hovertemplate I have created.

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly() 
fig <- fig %>%
  add_trace(
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'lines+markers',
    x = c(1,2,3,4,5),
    y = c(2.02825,1.63728,6.83839,4.8485,4.73463),
    text = c("Text A", "Text B", "Text C", "Text D", "Text E"),
    hovertemplate = paste('<i>Price</i>: $%{y:.2f}',
                        '<br><b>X</b>: %{x}<br>',
                        '<b>%{text}</b>'),
    showlegend = FALSE
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `<extra></extra>` tags to remove the extra box which is your trace0 tag like described here in the [docs](https://plotly.com/python/reference/?_ga=2.239496646.492206929.1678185355-1784655967.1677928623#scatter-hovertemplate) under hovertemplate. You could use the following code:

```r
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly() 
fig <- fig %>%
  add_trace(
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'lines+markers',
    x = c(1,2,3,4,5),
    y = c(2.02825,1.63728,6.83839,4.8485,4.73463),
    text = c("Text A", "Text B", "Text C", "Text D", "Text E"),
    hovertemplate = paste('<i>Price</i>: $%{y:.2f}',
                          '<br><b>X</b>: %{x}<br>',
                          '<b>%{text}</b>',
                          '<extra></extra>'),
    showlegend = FALSE
  ) 
fig
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Example without the trace0:

[image]